# Why is rails telling me User exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going through the well known Rails tutorial and I'm hitting something I don't understand.

If I try going against my validation routines by entering a user whose name or password is too short, when I try to do `user.save` in the rails console, the error I get is `User Exists`.

Why am I getting that particular error, which is of course not the right one? I do have a uniqueness validation set up, but that's not the one that should be triggered here.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50, minimum: 8 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 8 }
end
```

Comment: What does `User.all` return?

Comment: WAIT, WAIT, I just discovered `user.errors` and may have figured this out--- hold your answers

Comment: Okay, changing the question.

Comment: ahh you're using Postgres? What does your search path look like?

Comment: I don't know what a search path is in this context :)

Comment: Looking further into your updated question now :)

Comment: Also, please post the code for your model validation

Comment: run `users = User.all` then `users.destroy!` to clean out the database. After that, attempt creating a new user to test the validations

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that you added that user into the database before the validation was put into place?  I often have to clean out my test database when I change validation code.

Comment: Well, that wouldn't explain `User.count` returning `0`, nor why the Error message doesn't seem to correspond to the error.